# Conditional compilation with a if let enum matching which consists of one item

Tags: enums, rust

I have the following `enum`:

```
pub enum Game {
    Match(GameWorker),
    #[cfg(feature = "cups")]
    Cup(CupWorker),
}
```

So, this `enum` consists of one item if `cups` feature is disabled. The code below with `match` compiles okay but in place where I use `if let`s on matching this `enum` there is a error:

Working `match`:

```
fn clear(&mut self, silent: bool) {
    match *self {
        Game::Match(ref mut gm) => gm.clear(silent),
        #[cfg(feature = "cups")]
        Game::Cup(ref mut c) => c.clear(silent),
    }
}
```

`if let` which leads to a compile error:

```
let m: &mut Game = Game::Match(...);
if let Game::Match(ref mut gamematch) = *m {
    // ...
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0162]: irrefutable if-let pattern
   --> src/game.rs:436:32
    |
436 |                         if let Game::Match(ref mut gamematch) = *m {
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ irrefutable pattern
```

[Minimal example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=59933830de9f7ed68521e1ba48386de4&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Is there a way to allow such `if let`s ? I like this construction but somewhy it is not allowed to use it, I don't understand why. As shown above, `match` construction works okay in the same case. In my personal opinion here should be a silenceable `warning` instead of `error`.

Comment: I agree with you that I'd rather it be a warning. You may want to start a discussion on the Rust internals forum (https://internals.rust-lang.org/) or the reddit channel (https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/) to gauge the mood about moving this to a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if let` expects a refutable pattern, similar to how `if` expects a `bool`. You can't write `if () { something }`, even though `()` is "valid" in some sense. If you had `if () {} else { something_else }` it would be statically known that the else cannot occur.

Arguably `if true { something }` is also statically known, but there's a difference: The condition is a `bool`, which has two values, so even if you statically know the value, the type still offers multiple variants.

With `if let` it's the same, but you can use user defined types instead of just `bool`. If your enum has multiple variants, you can't statically decide that the if let is always taken. If the enum has a single variant, you know for a fact that the if condition is always true, so even if you had an `else` branch, it would not make any sense at all to exist.

Comment: I think that there's a big difference between the two though. It is known that `bool` will never get any other value, however it is not known that an `enum` will not.

Comment: Though I understand your answer, personally I do not treat this as a error. Yes, this branch will always be executed, so what? Why not to let it go? And example of `enum` shows good that we can't guarantee that the `if let` will compile because someday the `enum` may be changed because of conditional compilation and it will break everything. I don't think this is a good error, even more - that this is a problem. This makes sense only in certain well-defined situations where conditional compilation is absent.

Comment: "Why not to let it go?"  Because always taking one branch over the other is quite possibly a mistake the programmer isn't aware of.  `cfg!(...)` exists, though, which makes unconditional branching "useful" for `if`, but `if let` has no such use.  "... someday the `enum` may be changed ..."  Which is why Rust makes non-exhaustive matching a hard error, so that you're far less likely to forget to update matches after changing the enum.  Unconditional `if let` being a hard error makes sense if you consider the full context: Rust errs on the side of disallowing probable mistakes.

Comment: @DK. that sounds good but only sounds good. So, I have disabled some features and now my code does not compile. I have to rewrite it by using `match`es instead of `if let`. And so will happen more and more times because I will not trust `if let` anymore. Also, however, this **may** lead to a problem you wrote, this also **may not** lead to such problems in other cases, it depends on what engineer intentions were. So this definitely should be a silenceable warning instead of a error.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I didn't say it shouldn't be; I was trying to provide context as to why it's designed the way it is.  Degenerate enums caused by conditional compilation + `if let` is such a niche combination that it's possible very few people have ever had this problem.